# Linq Left Join where right is null

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

relatively new to linq, coming from SQL.  So, I'm trying to figure out left joins for the following:

```
SELECT * from MASTER m
LEFT JOIN CHILD C
    ON m.ID=C.MASTER_ID
WHERE C.MASTER_ID is null
```

So, normally this would return all of the records from Master that do not have a child.   I've discovered the .DefualtIfEmpty() but that doesn't eliminate the master records that have children.

I started along the lines of:

```
var recs=from m in MASTER
         from c in child
             .where (mapping=>mapping.MasterId == m.Id)
             .DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new { MasterId = m.Id};
```

But that's as far as I got and got stuck.   I'm assuming the .DefaultIfEmpty() isn't what I'm looking for.
Note:  The master table has a few million rows in it.  The children are close to the same count.   I only mention because it won't be efficient to pull back all of the records, etc.   Ideally, the SQL generated will look like the SQL I posted.

Thanks All.

Comment: See msdn website : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you all master records without children.

```
var recs = MASTER.Where(x => !child.Any(y => m.Id == c.MasterId));
```

the `!Any` will generate a `not Exists` SQL statement which will be translated into a `anti semi join` in the execution plan which is the best you can get for this type of check.

Comment: I looked at the query plan for the SQL that it produces and it looks about as optimized as I can get it.  Now with a few well placed indexes, I think I'll be gold.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using EF, then you can get the masters which don't have children using the navigation property that represent the children:

```
var result= from m in MASTER
            where m.Children.Count()==0// or m.Any()
            select m;
```

If you want to do it using an explicit join in linq you can try this:

```
var recs=from m in MASTER
         join c in child on m.Id equals C.MasterId into gj
         where gj.Count()==0 // or gj.Any()
         select m;
```

Comment: I like this approach too, but I'm not using EF in this particular project.  But, I have others that I do use and I'll be doing it this way with those projects.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can perform left outer join using Linq

```
var leftJoinResult = from m in MASTER join c in CHILD 
                   on m.ID equals  C.MASTER_ID 
                   into a
                   from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new {MASTER = m,
                               CHILD = b};
```

then eliminate the master records that have children

```
var result=leftJoinResult.where(x=>x.CHILD == null).select(y=>y.MASTER).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This solution only works if you have at least one row in child. The rows' ID doesn't matter.

```
var recs=from m in MASTER
         from c in child
             .where (mapping=>mapping.MasterId == m.Id)
             .DefaultIfEmpty() into fullC
         select new { MasterId = m.Id};
```

the keyword **into** does the magic. Adding it shows all rows, also those, which have NULL-Values in c.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue now, and neat SQL is a must and got it working in a very optimised way.

Linq:

```
var recs=from m in MASTER
         from c in child.where (mapping=>mapping.MasterId == m.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
         where c.Id == null  //Compiler creates a warning because int will never be null, but it works and creates outer left join
         select new { MasterId = m.Id};
```

Resulting SQL:

```
SELECT 
"Extent1"."Id" AS "MasterId"
FROM "DBO"."Master" "Extent1"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "DBO"."Child" "Extent2" ON "Extent2"."MasterId" = "Extent1"."Id"
WHERE ("Extent2"."Id" IS NULL)
```

This also work if you have more than one join condition
And also work for more than one left join

ps. I am using EF with Oracle, so not sure if this will be slightly different on the SQLServer provider for EF.