# C# Linq Lambda Left Join Where Right is Null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, where-clause

So I have a list of existing salesmen in a branch in `model.Salesmen` as `List<ApplicationUser>`.

I want to generate a list of all other users to populate a dropdown menu for easy additions. What I've written so far, inspired by [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023060/linq-left-join-where-right-is-null):

```
db.Users.Where(u => !model.Salesmen.Any(m => u.Id == m.Id)).OrderBy(u => u.Name).ToList();
```

The error I get:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Leads.Models.ApplicationUser'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you making a new post if the error is on the previous post?

Comment: How are you getting `model.Salesmen`?

Comment: @Danieboy the error is not on the previous point. That post gave me like 90% of the solution, but my case was a little different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put entire collection to lambda as EF cannot translate it to query. Do it like this:

```
var salesMenIds = model.Salesmen.Select(s => s.Id);
db.Users.Where(u => !salesMenIds.Contains(u.Id)).OrderBy(u => u.Name).ToList();
```